# How can I read json values from a file?

Tags: node.js

So basically I have these json values in my config.json file, but how can I read them from a .txt file, for example:

```
{"prefix": $}
```

This would set a variable configPrefix to $. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Could you include a little more about what you're trying to ask? Specifically, could you share your code that you've written to import this config.json file so that we can help debug it? Thanks!

Comment: You just entirely changed the meaning of your question after several of us have answered.  That is NOT permitted here on stack overflow.  I'm going to attempt to revert your edit.  You can ask a new and different question if what you originally wrote was not what you intended to ask or if you have another question.  Please follow the rules here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `require()` to read and parse your JSON file in one step:

```
let configPrefix = require("./config.json").prefix;
```

Or, if you wanted to get multiple values from that config:

```
const configData = require("./config.json");

let configPrefix = configData.prefix;
```

If your data is not actually JSON formatted, then you have to read the file yourself with something like `fs.readFile()` or `fs.readFileSync()` and then parse it yourself according to whatever formatting rules you have for the file.

Comment: But how do I read values like in a format like this from a .txt file? Say It's like prefix: $

Comment: @user9519736 - `require()` contains special logic for a text file that contains properly formatted JSON text with a `.json` file extension.   That's what my answer shows.  Your question says it's JSON so that's what I answered.  If the format of the data file is not JSON, then read the file with something like `fs.readFile()` into a string and then parse it yourself according to whatever format rules you intent (but that's not the question you asked).  I answered what you asked (a `.json` file containing valid JSON formatted data).

Comment: @user9519736 - In case you're not familiar with how stack overflow works, you ask a single clear question in your original question.  We then attempt to answer that. You don't keep asking more or different questions in comments.  If, after getting answers, you realize you also have a different question that isn't yet answered, then you can ask another, separate question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be reading this file just as the start of the program then go ahead and use `require` or `import` if you have babel. just a tip, suround the require with a `try` `catch` block to handle possible errors.

```
let config

try {
  config = require('path.to.file.json')
} catch (error) {
  // handle error
  config = {}
}
```

If you will be changing this file externally and you feel the need to source it then apart from reading it at the start you will need a function that uses `fs.readFile`. consider doing it like this and not with `readFileAsync` unless you need to block the program until you are done reading the config file.

After all of that you can do `const configPrefix = config.prefix` which will have the value `'$'`.